# Stop Certain Emails from Being Forwarded in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have forwarding enabled in my Gmail to another address. However, there is a certain kind of email (e.g. with a particular string in the body or subject) that I don't want to be forwarded. How can I achieve that?

I thoroughly examined Gmail filters but could not find anything for this purpose.